# how to encrypt the local form data on the device using ionic cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, local-storage

I have a cordova app which stores the offline forms on the device and once sync is done and app becomes online, all the data is send to the server.It is supporting both ios and android devices and in near future it will also support windows.I have googled it and found some plugins for the encryption like crypt-file.But could not find the proper documentation on how to use these and which one serves the purpose best.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: where exactly do you keep these forms?

Comment: This is far too broad.   Show your attempt at solving the problem (code!).

Comment: `found some plugins ... but could not find the proper documentation on how to use these` - my suggestion is to find some better documented plugins

Comment: @CommercialSuicide the form stores some text files, strings and images.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark i have not yet started coding because i m not able to finalise which encryption will be best suited for the app. The app will also have azure Ad and Intune integrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things are still not clear to me but if you want to use **cordova-plugin-crypt-file** then refer the below steps:

Step 1.Install cordova plugin using "cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-crypt-file".

Step 2.Change in plugin hook script places under "..\plugins\cordova-plugin-crypt-file\plugin.xml" for including and excluding files to encrypt.

```
<cryptfiles>
    <include>
        <file regex="\.(htm|html|js|css)$" />
    </include>
    <exclude>
    </exclude>
</cryptfiles>
```

Step 3.Run "cordova build"command to start build process. All the source files (HTML, CSS and JS) will be encrypted and bundled in ".apk" file.

*At the runtime, requested source file will be decrypted by decryption logic written in java file placed under "..\src\com\tkyaji\cordova\DecryptResource.java".*

**For DB label encryption use SQLCipher DB that is an SQLite extension that provide transparent 256-bit AES encryption for DB files.**

Comment: will this encrypt all the data stored on the local device. I have form data that is stored locally in the local storage of the device.When the app goes online sync is done with the server and the data is send to the server and new data is received which is again saved to local storage so that it can be used when the app is offline.

Comment: What do you mean by local storage of device? Shared preferences? If yes then you have to use the Encrypt data when storing to shared preferences and need to Decrypt before sending to server.

Comment: sqlite storage where all the data of the app is stored for offline use

Comment: This plugin only work in case of restricting to user to do reverse engineering on bundled apk. For SQLite dB SQLCipher is an SQLite extension that provide transparent 256-bit AES encryption for DB files.

Comment: Ok. I have installed SQLCipher , but is there any way to test whether the data is encrypted or not. Sorry for such silly questions, i m a newbie in ionic cordova apps.

Comment: You can verify the state of the database by pulling it off the emulator using adb: 
 adb pull /data/data/[your.package.name]/databases/[yourdatabase.db] 

Once you have your database locally, you can run hexdump -C 
[yourdatabase.db] to verify the contents of your database are encrypted. 
 Alternatively, you could also build the sqlcipher shell as documented 
[1] to interact with the database. 

    1. http://sqlcipher.net/introduction/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173593/discussion-between-puja-and-vikas-tandon).

Comment: when i add plugin to cordova using : cordova plugin add git clone https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.git to the root of the project.It gives me error : CordovaError: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "git". Please try adding it again.
    at new PluginInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginInfo/PluginInfo.js:367:15)

Comment: you don't required git clone.you can direclty run **"cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-crypt-file"** using plug man.